# Group By and Sum In LINQ query with Join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query in C# and i need to group by this query for c.Same_invoice and sum the column price in the row grouped.

I know how to do group by and sum but i don't know the solution for my case, with a join and a large amount of data.

The actual code is:

```
var query = from c in snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice
            select new{
               c.idexternal_invoices,
               c.businessname,
               o.number,
               c.message,
               c.price,
               c.date,
               c.iduser
            };
```

Thank to all

Comment: Joins are a very, very strong smell. The relation between the entities should be specified in their mapping. The ORM (eg EF) will generate the proper joins *only* when needed and only load the final data. In this case you wouldn't even need to group since you return all the root objects. A single `c.Invoices.Sum(inv=>inv.SomeField)` would be enough

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm working for a consultancy where the client has a project with Entity Framework but decided to not add mappings to database. I am not allowed to change the db or the mapping. I can only work with what I have. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Then tell them they have to fix their bug. In any case, it's impossible to help without knowing *what* you want to group or sum. How would you write the same statement in SQL? The LINQ statement would be equivalent. And the customer would still have a very ugly bug

Comment: What is `c.Same_invoice`? I don't see it in your sample query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
var query = from c in snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice into grouped
            select new{
               Invoice =grouped.key, Price = grouped.Sum(x => x.Price)};
```

Comment: I have try your code but c# doesn't recognize grouped point value

Comment: Sorry!In the select new my linq statement doesn't have any value in Grouped for the second part of join. I have only the first part

Comment: in grouped variable, you will have the c.idexternal_invoices as grouped.Key and groups from 2nd part of the join. You can modify this query as per your convenience like select new { ExternalInvoice = c, LinkedInvoices = Grouped } or select new { ExternalInvoice = c, PriceSum = Grouped.Sum(g => g.Price) }